# Object is supposed to be symmetrical, but the bottom edge is flattened, why?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting

The object is supposed to be symmetrical, but it printed with a flat edge. Cura 4.5 even generated support material to make it round, but then it came out like this:

[image: 3d object][image]

I tried printing it in the pegs straight down orientation, which was fine except it adds a crazy amount of support material.  So much it becomes hard to remove.

How can I prevent Cura from flatting the edge?  Or at least doing it much less than that.

[image]

I seen a overhang setting at 51 is that related?

The flat edge on the bottom was against the glass.

Comment: Can you add an image of the STL or link to the file? We have no clue how it is supposed to look. The image you posted of the print looks as if it is overextruded and printed too hot. The question also lacks printer and printer settings and material.

Comment: What other print settings did you have? I see a HUGE amount of ghosting there too (lower print speed for the outermost wall). A Snapshot of where you position it on the printer also migh thelp

Comment: Hm, now we know how it was supposed to look, but how did you pose it in Cura?

Comment: @Trish The edge that is flat that isn't supposed to be was against the print bed.

Comment: A guess: occasionally Cura goes crazy and leaves part of the design below bed level.  Try quitting & restarting Cura,  re-slice.  Then take a close look in "Layer View"

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have tried that and everything "looks" correct, but isn't.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but you have severe underextrusion and bed leveling and/or Z axis mechanical issues.